# Building a DIY Oscillocope

Tags: digital-logic, analog, oscilloscope, measurement

I have decided that I would like to design a DIY DSO Oscilloscope, the idea has been in my mind for a while, I just haven't had the time to look into it, I am surprised as there doesn't seem to be that much projects for digital storage oscilloscopes out there and if they are, they are often not well documented! I know it may take a while to build something accurate but I have the time.

Is the triggering for a DSO to be done in the digital domain or the analog front end?

Comment: Why do you think it’s better to make than buy?

Comment: And what have you decided about how much input bandwidth do you like? Sample rate? Bit resolution? And trace storage length?

Comment: Not too difficult to DIY a low-speed, low- to medium-precision data logger using just a microcontroller board and ADC. But making a scope with 100MHz signal bandwidth, with reasonable signal integrity, requires a sampling rate of at least 1GHz or better (10 sample points per signal cycle). That's far out of range of what can be achieved with solderless breadboard techniques and an Arduino. Think ECL buffers and squiggly matched-length stripline, multilayer PCB, and high-speed static RAM. The rest is a high-performance PC (or else you're building a USB Function box).

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I didn't say I think its better to make then to buy, I already have one, I would like to build one for the fun of it and because its something I am interested in.

Comment: @MarkU Would You say a 3.3 to 8MHZ 8BIT/6Msps is unrealistic?

Comment: I think DSO triggering is usually done in digital domain, to support "pretrigger". The DSO acquires and stores data, wrapping around like a FIFO buffer, while waiting for the trigger condition. When the trigger condition is met, some additional samples are acquired before the buffer is displayed on the screen. Acquiring N/2 samples puts the trigger in the center, so you can see events that happened before the trigger. Analog (CRT) scopes don't do that, pretrigger is a primary selling point of DSO.

Comment: @AliChen Around 3.3 to 8MHZ 8BIT/6Msps

Comment: 8-bit resolution at 6MSps is fast enough you'd definitely need a PCB layout, I'd recommend looking for a part that has an evaluation kit or development board or appnotes support. It's tricky to get good performance, and speaking as an applications engineer at a semiconductor company, we spend a lot of effort trying to provide good designs for customers to copy. Last thing I would want a customer to do is try to invent their own PCB layout without looking at what we've already tried. After all, we have to build a board when we take the graphs for the datasheet, so why not give out that board?

Comment: It's an interesting and attractive project, I'd probably start with the data logger idea first since that will give you some perspective of the real problem areas. Making it run fast enough and with enough bandwidth to be useful, and making a deep enough data buffer, while staying within cost budget, is quite a test. I think once you reach the point where it starts behaving like an oscilloscope, is the point where you've invested so much that it starts looking like a product. That's why you may find data logger tutorials but probably not full DSO tutorials.

Comment: The quality of triggering must not be underestimated when trying to sync noisy repetitive signals. So it depends on your expectations. Also the quality of averaging and buffer size for zoom must not be overlooked nor the nyquist filtering of signals at dynamic sweep rates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggering for DCO is probably the least important thing to worry about. There are more important things to be concerned with. For an oscilloscope to be useful, it must have:

1. High input impedance. However, high-speed signals is difficult to amplify at high-impedance. Most normal hi-speed amplifiers use 50-Ohm impedance, and you will need to have an active probe, which is a challenge on itself.
2. The scope must have variable gain, something from 5 mV/div, to 5 V/div, that's minimum. Therefore the front-end must have some variable-gain amplifier or electromechanical switch to provide 1-2-5-10-... scale, or about 10 steps, all needs to maintain good bandwidth.
3. The channels need anti-alising filter, so ADC wouldn't have spurious signals.
4. You will need a fast buffer memory, and an interface to transfer the buffered data into main PC for post-processing/re-scaing and display. In modern age the typical interface is USB 3.0.

Regarding sampling and bandwidth, for 8 MHz bandwidth you will need at least 20 Msps ADC, according to Kotelnikov-Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem. For 20 Msps you will need to work.

Regarding projects not being well documented, well, it is a complicated undertaking.

For 1MHz/1 Msps there are [instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/DPScope-Build-Your-Own-USBPC-Based-Oscilloscope/). For a wider range, up to 16 Msps, see this list of a dozen+ [DIY plans](https://www.mymydiy.com/diy-oscilloscopes/).

For a 20-80MHz project, you might find interesting the opensource SIGROK publication of the [Hantek 6052 PC-scope](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Hantek_6052BE), deposited to guthub.

For a medium high-end (1 GHz), the block diagram and reference to design kit is [given here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/386744/117785).

Comment: You may want to add a link to this: https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-High-speed-Oscilloscope-with-PC-interface/. The 2nd half describe how to use an external ADC and an external FIFO to collect samples much faster than an Arduino would normally be able to. It should have much higher performance than any other Arduino-based build.

Comment: @piojo, yes, there are many sources. On high end, Texas Instruments offers demo boards of this sort, Analog Devices/Linear Tech also have demo kits. This is an exiting topic.

Comment: I pointed that one out because it is cheap, fast, and doable. It's what I was going to build before I bought a Rigol instead. It higher spec than any plan in the DIY list, with the most expensive part being a fast FIFO. It's kind of a step between the lower caliber DIY plans and the block diagram.

Comment: @piojo, this project is not up to OP's task. The NE5534 has less than 200 kHz large amplitude bandwidth (at +-10V power supply) and can't work on 8 MHz signal. But the TLC5510 is adequate, I agree.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Still, changing the op amp seems like the easiest possible modification. I regret that I didn't make it myself, but I realized I'd eventually want a bench scope anyway.

Comment: While there's indeed a lot to scope beyond triggering, linking to the Hantek 6052 is actually a demonstration of why triggering cannot be overlooked. That design entirely lacks any hardware capable of making a triggering decision at full bandwidth, either before or after the ADC, and suffers extremely for it (the MCU's CPU core is not in the data path). This makes it all but unusable as an ordinary scope; its one virtue is the ability to do arbitrarily long captures streaming within the constraints of USB bandwidth - something rarely needed but when it is $60 is justified for that single task.

Answer (score 2):

Digital triggering after the ADC is cheap, but a well designed analog trigger can be better for raw performance and to avoid diluting your ADC bandwidth by sampling a channel you only intend to use as a trigger but not actually capture for display.

Of course digital triggering can have better support for patterns and rules, since it's just FPGA code.

Best solution? Support both.  In theory you can even honor the output of the analog trigger, or not, based on more analytical digital rules.

Any useful digital scope will of course support pre-trigerring by recording to a circular buffer until a set time after the trigger condition is met, then unwrapping for display. This can be done regardless if the trigger decision is an input to the digital system from an analog trigger circuit, or the output of a digital comparator or rule engine, or even the latter taking the former as one of its inputs.